# consumir web service en java

Tags: java, webservice

Soy nuevo en el tema de consumir web services, y quiero consumirlo en Java EE.Este es http://www.indicadoresdeldia.cl/webservice/indicadores.xml
no logro realizarlo, saludos de antemano

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado para consumir el servicio? ¿Qué problemas tienes al intentar consumirlo?

Comment: en netbeans intento web service client por url pero no me funciona, me lanza un error webservice client con not be created

Answer (score 2):

Segun el sitio http://www.indicadoresdeldia.cl/pages/code hay que consumir esta información como un archivo XML. El siguiente código funciona, es decir se conecta y consume el XML, en este caso imprimi la información vinculada a santoral y moneda, es sólo un ejemplo.

```
package com.proyecto.init;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        consumir();

    }
    public static void imprimeLista(NodeList lista)
    {
         for (int index=0;index<lista.getLength();index++)
            {
                   System.out.println(lista.item(index).getNodeName()+" "+lista.item(index).getTextContent());

            }

    }

    public static void consumir() throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException
    {
        URL url= new URL("http://indicadoresdeldia.cl/webservice/indicadores.xml");
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());    
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(input);
        NodeList listaSantoral = doc.getElementsByTagName("santoral").item(0).getChildNodes();
        NodeList listaMoneda=doc.getElementsByTagName("moneda").item(0).getChildNodes();
        imprimeLista(listaSantoral);
        imprimeLista(listaMoneda);


    }

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

En el siguiente link encuentras toda la informacion sobre webservices, en la parte final esta la explicacion paso a paso de como consumir un servicio web desde JAVA usando NetBeans:

http://www.jtech.ua.es/j2ee/publico/servc-web-2012-13/sesion01-apuntes.html

Espero te aclare las dudas, ya que tu pregunta es muy abierta.